# Avoid repeated binding of Events for dynamically added DOM elements?

Tags: jquery

In ready function I have a click function binding

```
$(function(){
   $(".classClick").click(function(){
     alert("Clicked");
   });
   $(selector).append("<div id="dynamic" class="classClick">Hello</div>");//Added after binding

});
```

The `dynamic` click event won't trigger because there was no such element while binding the `div`. I want't to trigger the event for all elements with `classClick` class (dynamic or not). How can I do this?

Update : **Also,**

I found it difficult to identify the function that executed the click event (from a large set of code). How can I adopt a better architecture, so that I can find out which function will be executed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
    $('body').on('click', ".classClick", function() {
        alert("Clicked");
    });
    $(selector).append('<div id="dynamic" class="classClick">Hello</div>');//Added after binding

});
```

**Update**

If I understand your second statement, you are having trouble with code organization due to the bloaty/spaghetti nature of jQuery.

I suppose a way which would improve readability would be to dynamically create the object with the event reference in it to allow for easier readability, for example:

```
$(function() {

    var functionToCall = function() {
        alert('clicked');
    };

    $('<div/>')
        .prop('id', 'dynamic')
        .text('Hello')
        .click(function() {
            functionToCall(); // This gives a little more visibility to what's happening on-click
        })
        .appendTo(selector);
});
```

Comment: I don't think I follow your update, could you please re-iterate?

Comment: Can I use `.classClick` instead of body and avoid it in the `on ` function?

Comment: That will be a good idea. Thank you. I have another idea. But don't know how better it would be.

Comment: You're most welcome. I hope it helped some. I think the best way to organize javascript code is to use one of the many MV* frameworks available, such as backbone or angular.

Comment: Suppose If I gave attribute names to elements like `data-mydivClick-blur` and always bind click and blur event using this attribute, How it will be? So that I can find out from the code base who used this attribute!

Comment: That's sounds very much like the way AngularJS does things, maybe you should check it out :)

Comment: You would need to still bind to the body, since you can't bind to elements that do not yet exist. So maybe $('body').on('click', '[data-click-action]', function() { //... });

Comment: Thank you! But your opinion about angular like attributes in jQuery